# How to combine two strings (date and time) to a single DateTime

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

I have two strings:

```
string one = "13/02/09";
string two = "2:35:10 PM";
```

I want to combine these two together and convert to a `DateTime`.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(one + " " + two);
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(one + " " + two, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: what exception is thrown ?

Comment: Consider parsing the date and times to `DateTime` objects separately and combine the components. Parsing the concatenated strings could lead to problems if you're not too careful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try like this;

```
string one = "13/02/09";
string two = "2:35:10 PM";

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(one + " " + two);
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(one + " " + two, "dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt1);
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/KqlpEh#view_edit_box)**.

*HH* using a 24-hour clock from `00` to `23`. For example; `1:45:30 AM -> 01` and `1:45:30 PM -> 13`

*h* using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12. For example; `1:45:30 AM -> 1` and `1:45:30 PM -> 1`

Check out for more information **[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)**

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with your hour specifier; you want `h` (*The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12*), not `HH` (*The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23*).

Answer (score 3):

I had different format and the above answer did not work:

```
string one = "2019-02-06";
string two = "18:30";
```

The solution for this format is:

```
DateTime newDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(one).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(two));
```

The result will be: newDateTime{06-02-2019 18:30:00}

Answer (score 2):

Try using a culture info which matches the `DateTime` format for your string values:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(one + " " + two,
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ro-RO"));
```

or modify the input string so that the hour has 2 digits:

```
string one = "13/02/09";
string two = "02:35:10 PM";
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(one + " " + two, 
    "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss tt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It still throws an exception.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, are you sure? Have you actually tested it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I did try it, but I must have pasted the wrong code! Have a +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the format string that you specify is not correct.

'HH' means a dwo-digit hour, but you have a single digit hour.

Use 'h' instead.

So the full format is 'dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss tt'

Comment: When you specify the exact format string, and there's no text in it (e.g. day names), the culture provided doesn't have much effect - I'm not sure it has _any_ effect here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string two = "02:35:10 PM";` instead of `string two = "2:35:10 PM";` and also `hh` instead of `HH` due to AM/PM format.

Below is the code:

```
string one = "13/02/09";
string two = "02:35:10 PM";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(one + " " + two, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This requires OP to have control over his inputs, which may not be the case. Why require him to change the inputs when it's possible to fix this by changing the format string _properly_?

Comment: I have deleted it, and indeed I have upvoted your answer! (I had some finger trouble where I was replying to a different answer than the one I intended to, I think because my internet connection went a bit weird for a bit. Sorry about the confusion.)

Comment: @Rawling: If he is given by values with various length without 0 in front of them and he is not able to fix this input format, then he can try to find another solution. This one is not a panaceum for all cases.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: Is ok now :)

Comment: @yBee No, if he is given values of various length without 0 in front of them, he can use the _correct format specifier_ `h` - rather than replacing one incorrect specifier, `HH`, with another one, `hh`.

Comment: @Rawling: I agree, your solution is more general.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want. I used the UK culture to take care of the d/m/y structure of your date:

```
        string string1 = "13/2/09";
        string string2 = "2:35:10 PM";
        DateTime combined = DateTime.Parse(string1 + ' ' + string2, new CultureInfo("UK"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses `DateTime.ParseExact` with your current thread's culture, so you can make things a bit clearer by simply doing:

```
string date = "13/02/09";
string time = "2:35:10 PM";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date +" "+ time, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
Console.WriteLine (dateTime);
```

That gives the result `13/02/2009 14:35:10`, and forces the parse to use the en-GB date time formats. If your Windows installation is en-GB anyway, you don't need the `CultureInfo(..)` argument.

Answer (score -1):

use DateTime.Parse () to parse the date and the time separately. Then add the time component of the second one to the first one, like this

```
var date = DateTime.Parse (one);
var time = DateTime.Parse (two);
var result = date + time - time.Date;
```

Comment: not working geting error : Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'