# Making a DateTime? from two strings for date and time

Tags: c#

My input I recieve two strings:

```
string1 = "12/15/2015"
string2 = "22:45"
```

How can I combine them to have a `DateTime?`  value.

Comment: Are the strings _always_ in those formats?  Have you looked at `DateTime.ParseExact`? If so, which part are you stuck on?

Comment: This question has been asked before on stack overflow. You can see the answer here: [How to combine two strings (date and time) to a single DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932950/how-to-combine-two-strings-date-and-time-to-a-single-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0} {1}",string1,string2));
```

Comment: is it wrong?  I was gonna test it.  What is vote down for?

Comment: This will throw a FormatException.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Really, cause it worked for me.  It really depends on your culture.

Comment: Ahh I missed the space between the args because I'm a derp. It's working.